# Is it OK for a view to know about its controller?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, nsnotificationcenter

I'd like my controller to subscribe to notifications from view. However, before doing that, I'd like to confirm if **it is OK for a view to know the instance of its controller?**

Let me offer you a more specific example of what I have in mind.

My controller creates the view and informs it that it is its controller

```
self.gameView = [[GameView alloc] initWithController:self];
```

Once done, it subscribes for notifications from this view

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                   selector:@selector(saySomething:)
                                   name:@"SaySomethingClever" object:nil];
```

Meanwhile the view does its thing, but when the right time comes, it posts a notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
                                        @"SaySomethingClever" object:gvc];
```

In order for it to do it, the view needs to know the recipient of the notification (gvc).

I'd like to use this opportunity and as you whether the following is ok:

When `initWithController` is called, the view

```
-(id) initWithController: (GameViewController* )g {
    gvc = g;
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300)];
}
```

where `initWithFrame:CGRectMake` is a private method that handles specific view stuff.

**Everything works fine, however, i wonder whether this approach is morally acceptable**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not strictly a problem if the view has a reference to its controller, but it looks like your real problem is a misunderstanding of the notification posting method.

The `object` argument isn't the receiver. Indeed, if it were -- if the poster of a notification had to know the object that was going to get the notification -- that would defeat the entire purpose of the notification. You could just call the appropriate method! The point of notifications is that the poster *doesn't* need to know the other objects which are listening.

The `object` argument is actually used *by the receiver* to distinguish which notifications it should care about. Most frequently, the argument is the poster itself:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IDidSomethingInteresting
                                                    object:self];
```

but it can in fact be any object.

When registering for notifications, you can specify a particular instance whose notifications you're interested in. This is the `object` argument to `addObserver:...` The notification center will then only pass on those notifications whose name *and* object match what was specified.

Even if you pass `nil` for the `object` in `addObserver:...`, you can check the object of a received notification and only act if the poster was one that you are interested in.

For example, there might be several windows in you application, and you may be interested in knowing when one of them is resized, but you don't care what happens to the rest of them. You would pass just that window instance as the `object` for `addObserver:...`

To sum up, your view in this case *doesn't* need that reference to its controller in order to for the controller to receive notifications posted by the view.

See also: ["Posting Notifications"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Posting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000724-CEGJFDFG)

Comment: Glad it's helpful! Felt a bit rambly when I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

While the concept is OK, it's not needed in your case:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SaySomethingClever"
                                                    object:self];
```

The object referenced by an `NSNotification` is usually the object which *posts* a notification. The whole notification idea is that posters don't need to know about observers.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on controllers calling other controllers (or ideally model methods).
Allow each view to work with it's main resource and allow the controller for that view to make additional calls.